# Strange (multiplied) PPM image after Sobel filtration

Tags: c, image-processing, ppm

I am having quite strange problem with my application which is meant to apply Sobel filter to the image.

The problem is that each time I have my image multiplied and moved a little. The multiplication number depends on the picture size.

This is an example how it looks like:

Initial image

[image: initial image]

After filtr added

[image: out picture]

For simplicity I am now working on one color only and one axe.

This is the code of Sobel filter:

```
///sobel code

        int SY[3][3]  = {{ 1,   2,   1},
                         { 0,   0,   0},
                         {-1,  -2,  -1}};

        int sobY,sobX,sobI,sobJ;
        long sumX,sumY;
        int SUM;

        for(sobX = 0;sobX<=(x-1);sobX++)
        {
            for(sobY = 0;sobY<=(y-1);sobY++)
            {
                sumY = 0;
                sumX = 0;

                if(sobY==0||sobY==(y-1))
                {
                    SUM = 0;
                } else if(sobX==0||sobX==(x-1))
                {
                    SUM = 0;
                } else
                {    
                    ///Y gradient
                    for(sobI=-1;sobI<=1;sobI++)
                    {
                        for(sobJ=-1;sobJ<=1;sobJ++)
                        {
                            sumY = sumY + (int)(red[sobX+sobI][sobY+sobJ] * SY[sobI+1][sobJ+1]);
                        }
                    }

                    SUM = abs(sumX) + abs(sumY);
                }

                if(SUM>255)
                    SUM = 255;
                if(SUM<0)
                    SUM = 0;

                outputRed[sobX][sobY] = 255 - SUM;
            }
        }
```

The simplified code along with sample image can be found here: https://db.tt/szpEMZ3f

I've tested reading and saving without filter so this fragment:

```
outputRed[sobX][sobY] = 255 - SUM;
```

looks like that

```
outputRed[sobX][sobY] = red[sobX][sobY];
```

and this works correctly.

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0):

Your dimensions of `SY` are `[3][3]` but you're initializing values up to `[2][14]`. This is classic undefined behavior.

Comment: It was not this, but thatnk you for pointing that out. I don't know how but those values where edited after I post it. Now I post correct ones.